# Powershell importBacpac to Azure fail when DB size is too large?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database

I use powershell to create SQL Azure databases from bacpac files. Sometimes I do however run into trouble when database size exeeds the default max size.

According to documentation it should be possible to add DB size to the ImportBacpac method but I'm not really sure how to use that in powershell.

Anyone who is restoring databases with altered database max size?

Documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870786.aspx

Current code

```
function restore-SQLBackup
([string]$ConnectionString = $(throw "The ConnectionString parameter is required."), 
[string]$DatabaseName = $(throw "The databaseName parameter is required."),
[string]$fileName = $(throw "The fileName parameter is required."), 
[string]$microsoftSqlServerDacPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll") {

Add-Type -Path $microsoftSqlServerDacPath

$Services = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $ConnectionString

if ($Services -eq $null)
{
    exit
}

$timeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss")

$bacpac = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage]::Load($fileName)
Write-Host "Starting restoring $DatabaseName at $timeStamp"
$Watch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.StopWatch
$Watch.Start()
$Services.ImportBacpac($bacpac, $DatabaseName)
$Watch.Stop()
Write-Host "Restore completed in" $Watch.Elapsed.ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to this:

```
$Watch.Start() 
$DatabaseSpecifications = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacAzureDatabaseSpecification
$DatabaseSpecifications.MaximumSize = 5 #5GB, based on your need
$Services.ImportBacpac($bacpac, $DatabaseName,$DatabaseSpecifications)
$Watch.Stop()
```

Here is the documentation I used: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacazuredatabasespecification.maximumsize.aspx

Here is the cmdlet for general database resizing: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj983732.aspx